# PHP/JavaScript login script refreshing when form is submitted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've created a login page using the following JavaScript:

```
    function handleLogin() {
    var form = $("#loginForm");    
    //disable the button so we can't resubmit while we wait
    //$("#submitButton",form).attr("disabled","disabled");
    var e = $("#username", form).val();
    var p = $("#password", form).val();

    console.log("click");
    if(e != "" && p != "") {
        //var str = form.serialize();
        //alert(str);
        $.ajax({ 
                 type: 'POST', 
                 url: 'http://localhost/php/log.php', 
                 crossDomain: true,
                 data:  {username: e, password :p},
                 dataType: 'json', 
                 async: false,

                 success: function (response){ 
                    alert ("response"); 
                    if (response.success) { 
                        alert("you're logged in");
                        window.localStorage["username"] = e;
                        window.localStorage["password"] = md5(p); 
                        //window.localStorage["UID"] = data.uid;           
                        window.location.replace("http://www.google.co.uk");
                    } 
                    else {

                        alert("Your login failed");
                        //window.location("main.html");
                    }


                 },
                 error: function(error){
                     //alert(response.success);
                    alert('Could not connect to the database' + error);
                    window.location = "index.html";
                }
        }); 
    }
    else {
        //if the username and password is empty
        alert("You must enter username and password");

    }
    return false;
    }
```

and the PHP in log.php is:

```
        $link = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("Could not connect to host.");
        mysql_select_db("$db_name", $link) or die("Could not find database.");


       $uname = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
       $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';



        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$uname' AND password = '$password'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        $num_row=mysql_num_rows($result);
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);


        if (is_object($result) && $result->num_rows == 1) {
        $response['success'] = true;

        }
        else
        {
        $response['success'] = false;
        }

        echo json_encode($response);

         //echo 'OK';
```

I would expect the page to show some error if the combination is wrong, or redirect to a different page if it's correct. However it just refreshes with the username/password in the url.

Log in form

```
<form id="loginForm" method="post">
      <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="Username" />
  </div>
      <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password" />
  </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" id="submitButton">
    </form>
```

Comment: Change your form `method` to `post`

Comment: it's already using post?

Comment: I don't see the reason why the username and password should be displayed in your URL. Other than that, you need to correct two things: 1) `mysql_query` returns a resource and you're checking for object 2) Even if no match found, you are still returning a `success` index. Forgot to mention, it's `mysql_num_rows`, what's `$result->num_rows` there?

Comment: Can you post `#loginForm` please? The behavior you describe sounds like the data isn't being sent by POST. I know you have it set in AJAX but let's see all of the code before discounting that.

Comment: What alert do you see? do you see any alert out of the 3 you given?

Comment: I don't see any alerts

Comment: I've updated my question with the form code

Comment: Has the html form been set to post? There is no event.PreventDefault so could be just posting the form using GET.

Comment: yes, the form code is now in my question

Comment: I am assuming that the handleLogin() javascript function should take over the submit event for the form?  But I don't see that being set anywhere.you should $('#loginForm').submit(handleLogin); somehwere in a document ready

Comment: When is the form submit actually being triggered? doesn't seem as though the js function is being triggered by a click or anything, so the form would just default to a standard POST.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your html container as follows

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="Username" />
  </div>
      <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password" />
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="Login" id="submitButton" onclick="handleLogin()">
```

Since, you are submitting data using ajax, then you dont need to writt "form" tag in your html

Total page would be refresh when click "Submit" button. so I have changed as "button" and provide the ajax method in "onclick" attribute

Sample PHP file (index.php) that I tried without connecting DB for testing yours scenario

```
<?php
if($_POST){
    if($_POST['username'] == "admin" && $_POST['password'] == "admin"){
        $response['success'] = true;
    }else{
        $response['success'] = false;
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}
?>
```

modified your js code

```
function handleLogin() {
    var e = $("#username").val();
    var p = $("#password").val();

    if(e != "" && p != "") {
        $.ajax({ 
                 type: 'POST', 
                 url: 'index.php', 
                 crossDomain: true,
                 data:  {username: e, password :p},
                 dataType: 'json', 
                 async: false,

                 success: function (response){ 
                    alert ("response"); 
                    if (response.success) { 
                        alert("you're logged in");
                     } 
                    else {
                        alert("Your login failed");
                    }
                 },
                 error: function(error){
                    alert('Could not connect to the database' + error);
                 }
               }); 
    }
    else {
        alert("You must enter username and password");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: So this has made me get an alert with Your login failed, however the username and password are definitely correct...

Comment: that is different issue..please track the ajax request (using firebug or someother tool) and check the "user" table...your provided username and password there?

Comment: please change this line  " if (response.success) { " to "if (response.success == "true") { "

Comment: I have update the post. please check and let me know.

Comment: is it something to do with what I have in my php file

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery (version 1.10.1), you can bind the click event directly to your forms submit button

```
$(document).on('click', '#submitButton', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   ... See detailed jsFiddle example ...

   return false;
});
```

With `preventDefault()`, you remove the default submit behavior of the Submit button, so the page won't be reloaded after form submit.

Also use form attributes like action to provide ajax URL, or method, for setting ajax request type.

**P.S** This type of binding won't work for jQuery 1.6

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Uzkwm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `if(response.responseText)`